# How to call an object with the character variable of the same name

Tags: r, r-faq

I'm trying to write a function in R to batch-analyse a number of files in a similar manner. The files are of class `ExpressionSetIllumina`. I can make a character (string) vector with names of all files in the directory and load each of them:

```
list = list.files()
for (i in list[1]) {    
  load(i)
}
```

This loads files correctly

```
> ls()
[1] "i"                    "list"                 "SSD.BA.vsn"
> class(SSD.BA.vsn)
[1] "ExpressionSetIllumina"
attr(,"package")
[1] "beadarray"
```

What I want to do now is to use `i` (character string `"SSD.BA.vsn"`) to assign object `SSD.BA.vsn` to a new object data so that:

```
>data = SomeFunction(i)
>class(data)
[1] "ExpressionSetIllumina"
attr(,"package")
[1] "beadarray"
```

But whatever I've tried so far just returns data as a character vector of the same value as i or doesn't work at all. So I wonder if there's a function that would do it for me or whether I need to go about it some other way.

I have the name of an object or variable stored as a string in a character vector. How can I use the string object name to do something to the object?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think you want [`get`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/get).

```
data <- get(i)
```

That said, once you start using `get` (and its counterpart, [`assign`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/assign)), you usually end up with horrible unreadable code.

For batch analyses like yours, it is often better to read all your data into a list of data frames, then make liberal use of [`lapply`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/lapply).  Something like:

```
data_files <- list.files()
all_vars <- lapply(data_files, function(file)
{
  vars_loaded <- load(file)
  mget(vars_loaded, parent.frame())
})
```

`mget` is the version of `get` that retrieves multiple variables at once.  Here it is used to retrieve all the things that were loaded by the call to load.

Now you have a list of lists: the top level list is related to the file, lower level lists contain the variables loaded from that file.

Comment: Just what was needed. Thank you! But I will keep your suggestion about code readability in mind.