# Get a function from a string of the form "package::function"

Tags: r

[There has been discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083907/how-to-call-an-object-with-the-character-variable-of-the-same-name) on how to get a variable from a string. Indeed, `get` works for, say, the `data.table` function: `get("data.table")` returns `data.table`. However,

```
> get("data.table::data.table")
Error in get("data.table::data.table") : 
  object 'data.table::data.table' not found
```

Is there a way to do this that preserves the reference to the package name? I.e., I do NOT want to simply do a split on "::" and get the second half of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use the `envir` argument to get the function from the namespace.

```
get("data.table", envir = getNamespace("data.table"))
```

Or more simply as @joran notes, `getFromNamespace()` can be used.

```
getFromNamespace("data.table", "data.table")
```

Comment: Or `getFromNamespace` I suppose.