# How to correctly evaluate a literal character vector

Tags: r, parsing, eval

Let's assume I have the following object in R:

```
QXX_my_vector <- "c(\"Element 1\", \"Element 2\", \"Element 3\", \"Element 4\")"
```

I want to turn this into a true character vector containing the four elements.

I can do this via `eval(parse(text = QXX_my_vector))` which gives:

```
# [1] "Element 1" "Element 2" "Element 3" "Element 4"
```

My problem/question is: I want to dynamically pass the text element into the parse function, i.e.:

```
question_stem = "QXX"
eval(parse(text = paste0(question_stem, "_my_vector")))
```

However, this gives:

```
# [1] "c(\"Element 1\", \"Element 2\", \"Element 3\", \"Element 3\")"
```

I also tried to wrap the `paste0` part into a `sym` function, but this gives the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `get`: `eval(parse(text = get(paste0(question_stem, "_my_vector"))))`

Comment: Ah, get! Thanks, works perfectly fine. If you want to turn it into ans answer, I gladly accept (although I suspect that such an easy answer indicates that my question is probably a duplicate).

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083907/how-to-call-an-object-with-the-character-variable-of-the-same-name ?

Comment: Yep, `get´ was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `get` to get an object with the given name.

```
eval(parse(text = get(paste0(question_stem, "_my_vector"))))
#[1] "Element 1" "Element 2" "Element 3" "Element 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use str_extract

```
library(stringr)
 str_extract_all(get(paste0(question_stem, "_my_vector")), '(?<=")[^",)]+')[[1]]
[1] "Element 1" "Element 2" "Element 3" "Element 4"
```